# Why my ft_print_comb function does not give any output?

Tags: c, unix, system, call

```
#include<stdio.h>   
#include<unistd.h>

void ft_putchar(char x){
    write(1, &x, 1);
}
void ft_print_comb()
{
    char i, j, k;
    i = '0';
    while(i <= 7){
        i++;
        j = i+1;
        while(j <= 8){
            j++;
        
            k = j+1;
            while(k <= 9){
                k++;
                    ft_putchar(i);
                    ft_putchar(j);
                    ft_putchar(k);
                    ft_putchar(',');
                    ft_putchar(' ');
            }
            }
        }
}
int main(){
    ft_print_comb();
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to do couple changes but it either broke the code or kept giving me no output. What I am trying to do is create a function that displays all different combinations of three different digits in
ascending order, listed by ascending order. for loop and printf functions are not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `char`s, you should compare with character literals instead of integers. For instance, the `while` loop is never entered because the ASCII code for '0' is 48, which is greater than 7.

```c
while (i <= '7') {
    j = i + 1;
    while (j <= '8') {
        k = j + 1;
        while (k <= '9') {
            ft_putchar(i);
            ft_putchar(j);
            ft_putchar(k);
            ft_putchar(',');
            ft_putchar(' ');
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: 've just tried it. It definitely made my program work but it gave me an output like this 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 13:, 146, 147, 148, 149, 14:, 157, 158, 159, 15:, 168, 169, 16:, 179, 17:, 18:, 246, 247, 248, 249, 24:, 257, 258, 259, 25:, 268, 269, 26:, 279, 27:, 28:, 357, 358, 359, 35:, 368, 369, 36:, 379, 37:, 38:, 468, 469, 46:, 479, 47:, 48:, 579, 57:, 58:, 68:, 
here's what i want
 012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, ..., 789$>

Comment: @wrut Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sure, i am trying to write a function called ft_print_comb that displays all different combinations of three different digits in ascending order, listed by ascending order.   It basically gives an output like this 012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, ..., 789$

Comment: @wrut Move the increment to the end of each loop. See the updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i is a character with a value of 48 (the ASCII code of '0') so the while loop is never entered.  Set i this way:

```
i = 0;
```

Comment: The ASCII code of `0` is 48. 60 is ASCII code for `<`.

Comment: Oops you are correct I was looking at the octal values.

Comment: i have tried changing it but it gave me the output of
, , , ,      , 
, , , ,         , 
, , ,      , 
, ,  , 
,      , 
, 
, , , ,         , 
, , ,      , 
, ,  , 
,      , 
, 
, , ,      , 
, ,  , 
,      , 
, 
, ,  , 
,      , 
, 
,      , 
, 
, 
,